# How did they solve this definite double integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

This is the double integral I found online. FYI, this is a problem about electric flux density but I decided to post it here since my concern is only about the integral.

$$D=\frac{60\times10^{-6}}{2{\pi}r^2}\cdot\iint_{\phi,r=0}^{\phi=2\pi, r=\infty}r\ drd\phi$$
$$D=\frac{60\times10^{-6}}{2{\pi}r^2}\cdot\frac{r^2}{2}\cdot\int_{\phi=0}^{\phi=2\pi}d\phi$$
$$D=\frac{60\times10^{-6}}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{2\pi}{2}$$
$$D=\frac{60\times10^{-6}}{2}$$
$$D=30 \ uC$$

This is how I try to solve it, let's just focus on the double integral first.

$$\iint_{\phi,r=0}^{\phi=2\pi, r=\infty}r \ drd\phi$$

Solving for the first integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty}r \ dr$$
$$\int r \ dr$$
$$\frac{r^2}{2}$$
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}t^2-0^2$$
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}t^2$$
$$\int_0^{\infty}r \ dr = \infty$$

Thus, it is divergent. Thus, I cannot proceed to solve as they were able to do. Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you have taken out the !/r^2 term which was there in the original integral. With this, I think the integral converges :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you might misterpreted, r^2/2 is the answer for the indefinite integral of r. As for the limit, I have taken out the 1/2 since it is constant.

Comment: Most probably your formulation is incorrect. Can you please tell me exactly what you were working on? Probably I can help.

Comment: @Ishraaq Even after that the integral will be divergent.

Comment: I'm working on solving the total electric flux passing through plane z.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez So, they are wrong?

Comment: @Abdul $z$ is a axis, not a plane. Do you mean $xy$ plane?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari I'm not really sure, the problem stated through plane z =26 cm.

Comment: @Abdul Ok, I got it.

Comment: I managed to evaluate the electric flux through the plane. I don't think electric flux density will be easy to evaluate, because the area is not constant.

Comment: Given that there's an $r$ appearing as a variable in the expression, and also as a variable of integration, I suspect something's gone wrong somewhere. Can you link to where you found this integral?

Comment: @ConMan read all the comments, you will understand everything.

Comment: You need to edit your question to write as stated, rather than part of the question. Also clearly state what you have done and what help you are expecting. What you have written in the question at this point does not make sense.

Comment: @ConMan  Is the first solution with D = the work you found online?  and like ConMan, evaluating the first integral with r= 0 to 00 doesn't make sense with r^2  also previously outside the integral.